# Ext.Component.setStyle('color', 'value') does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two buttons, the idea is to click one and have the text of the other change color i.e. if button one is clicked, the text of button two changes from its current color to blue and vice-versa.
I'm getting a reference to the buttons and calling setStyle on the  reference but it seems not to work. Any insight is welcome. Code snippet can be found below:-

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Foo',
    id: 'foo',
    ui: 'plain',
    toggleGroup: "buttonToggle",
    listeners: {
        click: "onFooButtonClick",
        afterrender: 'onButtonsRendered'
    },
    toggleHandler: "onButtonToggled"
},
{
    xtype: 'tbseparator'
},
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Bar',
    id: 'bar',
    ui: 'plain',
    toggleGroup: "buttonToggle",
    listeners: {
        click: "onBarButtonClick",
        afterrender: 'onButtonsRendered'
    },
    toggleHandler: "onButtonToggled"
}

// Controller.js

onButtonToggled: function(button, state) {
    var clickedButton = button.id;
    button.btnInnerEl.setStyle('color', 'black');     
    if (clickedButton === "foo") {
        var btnBar = Ext.getCmp('bar');
        btnBar.setStyle('color', 'blue');
    } else if (clickedButton === "bar") {
        var btnFoo = Ext.getCmp('foo');
        btnFoo.setStyle('color', 'blue');
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it work I had to also call **btnInnerEl** on both btnFoo and btnBar.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'setStyle' method is wrong. You have to use curly braces and need to add color as a key-value manner like this:

So you need to replace below code:

```
btnBar.setStyle('color', 'blue');
btnFoo.setStyle('color', 'blue');
button.btnInnerEl.setStyle('color', 'black');
```

with this:

```
btnBar.setStyle({'color': 'blue'});
btnFoo.setStyle({'color': 'blue'});
button.btnInnerEl.setStyle({'color': 'black'});
```

Hope it helps.